# Opentelemetry integration with Nagios or PRTG

Tags: nagios, open-telemetry, prtg

To monitor services and software we would like to start using Opentelemetry.

We saw that there are many tools for visualizing the results of such controls. Is it possible to get information from Opentelemetry and visualize them on Nagios or PRTG dashboards?

Answer (score 1):

I would say you have wrong expectations about "get information from Opentelemetry". Opentelemetry is "integration" layer between collection of observability data (logs, metrics, traces) and their data storages. You don't need to stuck with one vendor, but you can combine them. E.g. you will use Telegraf to collect metrics, but you will store those metrics in the Prometheus.

So the answer doesn't depend on Opentelemtry. It depends on your observability data storage(s) - those must be supported by your tools (Nagios, PRTG dashboards).